# How can i align my items left and shrink them

Tags: html, css

Im currently building a simple resume website but  when i try to align my skills bar to left and trying to make them small but couldn't do it how can i do it i searched a little bit but those werent helpful thanks in advance.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.html {
  width: 40%;
  animation: html 2s;
}

body {
  background: burlywood;
}

.skills {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  color: gray;
}

.skills li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.bar {
  background: gray;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(43, 41, 41);
}

.bar span {
  height: 2px;
  float: left;
  background: cyan;
}

.py {
  width: 20%;
  animation: py 2s;
}

.word {
  width: 50%;
  animation: word 2s;
}

.excel {
  width: 70%;
  animation: excel 2s;
}

.c {
  width: 59%;
  animation: c 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h1>Skills</h1>
  <li>
    <h3>C++</h3>
    <span class="bar"><span class="c"></span></span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h3>Microsoft Excel</h3>
    <span class="bar"><span class="excel"></span></span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h3>Microsoft Word</h3>
    <span class="bar"><span class="word"></span></span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h3>Python</h3>
    <span class="bar"><span class="py"></span></span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h3>HTML</h3>
    <span class="bar"><span class="html"></span></span>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: hi. also, show your html, pls.

Comment: i added it check now

Comment: Your requirement is not entirely clear. But if you set `margin: 60px 0;` and `width: 250px;` to `.skills`, will you get the result you want?

Comment: im new to css im trying random numbers

Comment: max-width instead of width

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that you have not wrapped all the `<li>` tags in the `<ul>` tag. I edited your question to include the `<ul>` tag.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov please don't edit the OP code to correct it. The issue can be related to the wrong code that you corrected

Comment: @TemaniAfif, good. I'll take that into account. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't wrapped your `<li>` tags in a `<ul` (or `<ol>`) tag, which is an error in the html structure. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).

Also, for correct alignment, you can change the **margin** rule to `.skills`, and the **width**. I reduced the **width** by a factor of 2 = 250px, but you can set your value as the **width**:

```
.skills {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 60px auto 60px 60px;
  color: gray;
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.html {
  width: 40%;
  animation: html 2s;
}

body {
  background: burlywood;
}

.skills {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 60px auto 60px 60px;
  color: gray;
}

.skills li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.bar {
  background: gray;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(43, 41, 41);
}

.bar span {
  height: 2px;
  float: left;
  background: cyan;
}

.py {
  width: 20%;
  animation: py 2s;
}

.word {
  width: 50%;
  animation: word 2s;
}

.excel {
  width: 70%;
  animation: excel 2s;
}

.c {
  width: 59%;
  animation: c 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
    <h1>Skills</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3>C++</h3>
            <span class="bar"><span class="c"></span></span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h3>Microsoft Excel</h3>
            <span class="bar"><span class="excel"></span></span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h3>Microsoft Word</h3>
            <span class="bar"><span class="word"></span></span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h3>Python</h3>
            <span class="bar"><span class="py"></span></span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h3>HTML</h3>
            <span class="bar"><span class="html"></span></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @EMREDAL, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is how you are setting your margin.  Using auto for the right, left values will center it.  Try something like this (I also changed your width to percentage but not really clear on what you mean by "make them small")

```
.skills {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 60px 0;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont find flex container, you have container with flex and into you can have boxes with flex-start.